# Atom: select all occurrences at once

Tags: atom

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will select one occurrence. Pressing it again will select another occurrence. We need to press it over and over until confident has select all occurrence.

Is there any way to select all occurrence at once?

(In VS Code, the shortkey is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>)

Below is my software version:

- Atom version: 1.13.0
- Ubuntu release: 16.04 x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a selection then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>

source: https://discuss.atom.io/t/select-all-and-edit-all-at-once/25220/5

Comment: Not working for me. Sublime 3 also not working but old Sublime 2 working.

Answer (score 0):

Even David answer is correct I found useful having all related shortcuts together:

- <kbd>ctrl - d</kbd> to select one at a time.
- <kbd>alt - F3</kbd> to select all at once
- <kbd>ctrl - u</kbd> doesn't work even *Settings > Keybindings* say it should, **but**:
- <kbd>ctrl - k</kbd><kbd>ctrl - d</kbd> skip select (**very useful**).
- <kbd>esc</kbd> to undo all.

More info in/with `python -m json.tool /usr/share/atom/resources/app/node_modules/find-and-replace/keymaps/find-and-replace.json | less`. Said [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/multiple-selections/755/57?u=pabloab).